# AngularJS on Android 2.2

Tags: android, angularjs

I am involved in a new web site project (no PhoneGap or Cordova) and the site should work on older Android browsers as well. AngularJS is on the tech list but its FAQ doesn't mention any versions for supported mobile browsers.

Has anyone encountered any issues using AngularJS on Android 2.2?

Comment: AngularJS is a JavaScript framework.  It does not include a UI library.  What type of support are you looking for?  Have you run into any specific problems?

Comment: As AngularJS uses browser JavaScript implementation for bindings, directives etc there is a good chance not everything works perfectly on older devices&browsers.